# Is there a Hamiltonian simulation technique implemented somewhere?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, hamiltonian-simulation

I was wondering if there was some code available for Hamiltonian simulation for sparse matrix. And also if they exist, they correspond to a divide and conquer approach or a Quantum walk approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update on the subject: there are several implementations in the wild. I don't know if you still need them, but even if you don't it will hopefully be useful to other people.

I chose to list the implementations by "provenance" rather than by the algorithm used because there are not that much implementations. This may change in the future.

1. **Qiskit-aqua**: Qiskit is the library of IBM for quantum computing. [Qiskit-aqua](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua) is the part of the library that deals with quantum algorithms.

   The Qiskit-aqua implementation can only simulate Hamiltonians that are a sum of hermitian matrices that can be written as tensor products of Pauli operators. To do so, they used the Trotter-Suzuki formula.

   The documentation is available [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/qiskit.aqua.operators.html#module-qiskit.aqua.operators).
2. **simcount**: Implementation of 3 hamiltonian simulation algorithms for a specific kind of hamiltonian. Based on [Quipper](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/%7Eselinger/quipper/). All their work is explained in the paper [Toward the first quantum simulation with quantum speedup (Andrew M. Childs, Dmitri Maslov, Yunseong Nam, Neil J. Ross, Yuan Su, 2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10980).

   The 3 algorithms (and their variations) implemented in the repository have been optimised for a very specific Hamiltonian $$H = \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \vec{\sigma}_j \cdot{} \vec{\sigma}_{j+1} + h_j \sigma_j^z \right).$$

   The implementations are available [here](https://github.com/njross/simcount).
3. **QatHS** (disclaimer: I did this one): Implementation of the Trotter-Suzuki formula along with Hamiltonian Simulation algorithms for black-box oracles. The oracle-based Hamiltonian Simulation algorithms are based on a Master thesis [available here](https://prism.ucalgary.ca/handle/1880/41417)  (requires to ask for the PDF, I could not find it elsewhere).

   In short: you can simulate any Hermitian matrix as long as you have an oracle for each of the matrices in your decomposition. Integer-weighted matrices have been extensively tested with the wave equation solver implementation, fixed-points weighted matrices should also work but have not been tested as thoroughly.

   The implementation is available [here](https://gitlab.com/cerfacs/qaths).

Comment: The 2nd link ("...is available here") is dead. Could you update this?

Comment: I realised this yesterday, I'll update the whole answer shortly (4-5 hours).

Comment: I'd also very much appreciate it if you include new Hamiltonian simulation software/methods. Additionally, I have a clarifying question. Does Hamiltonian simulation imply simulating only the form $e^{-iAt}$ or can it also refer to the more general form $e^{At}$?

Comment: Done! And about your question, $e^{-iAt} = \left( e^{iAt} \right)^\dagger$, so yes you can simulate the general form as well, just by inverting the quantum circuit (or giving a negative time).

Comment: Great, I appreciate the update! As for my question, I am specifically interested in estimating $e^{At}$, so what I was wondering is if Hamiltonian simulation refers specifically to estimating $e^{iAt}$ or if it also refers to the exponentiation of any matrix (e.g $e^{At}$).

Comment: I found an answer to my own question. From (https://www.cs.umd.edu/~amchilds/qa/qa.pdf) on page 125 it says "Another way of combining  Hamiltonians comes from commutation: if $H_1$ and $H_2$ can be efficiently simulated, then $i[H_1,H_2]$ can be efficiently simulated." So as I understand it, if I find an algorithm which simulates the Hamiltonian of $H$ then I can also simulate the Hamiltonian of $iH$.

Answer (score 3):

[In this article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00268976.2012.668289) the authors stated that they used this [Group Leader's algorithm](https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1762&context=nanopub) in order to obtain the circuit implementing the hamiltonian simulation used as a subroutine in an instance of *HHL* algorithm.

Unfortunately though, I did not understand quite well how they actually managed to find the circuit with that method.

Comment: I know this one and I understand it well. I even did an implementation on it. But I want actually something that is not using this one. Either divide and conquer algorithms or quantum walks with a real code. The GLOA can be long to run actually.