# How to perform a time evolution of a quantum state with Qiskit Aqua?

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

How can we perform a time evolution of a quantum state for a given Hamiltonian with qiskit Aqua operator flow? I'm interested in it due to its higher efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very general question, and I myself am only beginning to learn how to implement Hamiltonian simulations on Qiskit, but here are some resources which may be useful.

[This Stack Exchange thread](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5567/circuit-construction-for-hamiltonian-simulation) details basic theory of Hamiltonian simulation.

[This tutorial](https://github.com/DavitKhach/quantum-algorithms-tutorials/blob/master/Hamiltonian_simulation.ipynb) on Hamiltonian simulations outlines how to implement a basic one assuming you have already decomposed your matrix into component Pauli matrices. I myself am looking to learn how to automatically decompose a Hermitian matrix into its Pauli matrices using qiskit if possible.

Additionally, I am linking a similar thread [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4017/is-there-a-hamiltonian-simulation-technique-implemented-somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your Hamiltonian written in terms of the Pauli gates $\{I,X,Y,Z\}$, you can evolve your circuit in time simply by creating an unitary time-evolution operator with the `Operator.exp_i()` attribute and applying it to the circuit with `QuantumCircuit.unitary()`. Have a look at my [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqkyCsvQYy8nuO86yD3IBHQ), where I explain in great detail how to do that.